# %d formatting for both 32-bit and 64-bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

```
NSInteger precedence = [self operatorPrecedence];
[d appendFormat:@"precedence:%d, ", precedence];
```

gives:

> Warning: Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
>   'NSInteger' (aka 'long')

and Xcode suggests to change `%d` to `%ld`.

However, it only works for either 32-bit *or* 64-bit target, as `NSInteger` is:

```
 #if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
 typedef long NSInteger;
 typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
 #else
 typedef int NSInteger;
 typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
 #endif
```

What's the best way to kill the warning, for both 32-bit and 64-bit targets?

Comment: If you're supporting 10.8 & newer only, you don't even have to compile for 32-bit (32-bit machines can't run 10.8).

Comment: The code runs on both OS X and iOS.

Comment: %ld without cast quiets the warning in Xcode 5.1. Is it safe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Follow [the instructions in Apple's 64-Bit Transition Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/ConvertingExistingApp/ConvertingExistingApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004247-CH5-SW6).

For an `NSInteger`, use `%ld` and cast the value to `long`.

```
[d appendFormat:@"precedence:%ld, ", (long)precedence];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

**UPD:**

```
NSInteger precedence = [self operatorPrecedence];
[d appendFormat:@"precedence:%ld, ", (long)precedence];
```

Comment: This will truncate some values in 64-bit since `NSInteger` is a 64-bit type while `int` is only 32-bit.